# How to show the elements of a list in another list typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

How to show elements in `statusList2` in the `statusList1` loop?

`service.statusList1` contains two elements -> [0], [1]

`service.statusList2` contains two elements -> [0], [1]

```
 <tr *ngFor="let status1 of service.statusList1; index as i">

      <td>{{status1}}</td>

      <td>{{service.statusList2[i]}}</td>

      {{i+1}}
 </tr>
```

I use Angular 6.

JavaScript old school is something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < someArray.length ; i++) {
  let item = someArray[i];
}
```

I want to understate simply Angular 6 loop by index example

```
<tr *ngFor="let status1 of service.statusList1; index as i">

         <!-- <td>{{status1}}</td> -->          
         <td>{{service.statusList1[i]}}</td>

          {{i+1}}
     </tr>
```

I did create https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1m31pe
If somebody can edit example???

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: In your above example, replace `index as i` with `let i = index`. That should be enough

Comment: If I use let i = index , should I need to delete  {{i+1}}  ?

Comment: @Rajat https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1m31pe

Comment: @igg you are correct. Please add post to give you one point +

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the '`Hello`' component. Rest seems to be working. I just changed the `app.component.ts` to:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

    array1: Array<string> = ["Hi","Hi2"];
  array2: Array<any> = [{name: "No hi"},{name:"no hi2"}];
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptut1t) is the updated Stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

It is turn out very simple solution. Just need to use let and that is all.

```
 <tr *ngFor="let a of arr1; let i = index">    
    <td>{{a.name}}</td>
    <td>{{arr2[i].name}}</td>
</tr>
```

The correct one is here
https://angular-jqqmbq.stackblitz.io